# Angular Effect not getting called

Tags: angular, ngrx

I could be wrong with the title but I have done all the research I could and it all looks right to me.

Here is the [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnc481) for the store I have setup. For some reason the pickupData is returning undefined in my selector which has me thrown off a bit.

I have the effect added to the the app.module file and I am trying to call it in my component like

```
public driverData$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getPickupData));
```

Comment: stackblitz shows nothing, are you making sure that you dispatched the right action to trigger said effect?

Comment: Sorry pretty sure it is fixed @MikeTung. So I am just going to dispatch the fetch_pickup_success?

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying now. Trying to implement it now. Thank you

Comment: Yeah that was the trick. Somehow I missed dispatching that action. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's problem was solved by dispatching an action first to trigger his effect.